# how to join 2 sql ( sum(table 1) and count(table 2 ) ) and group by date from table 1?

Tags: mysql, sql

first table and second table relate by id_sold

query in table 1  as "SALE TABLE"

```
select tanggal as date_sold, count(kd_op_beli_tunai) as quantity_id_sold
from t_pembelian_tunai
group by tanggal
```

result 1

[image]

query in table 2 as "DETAIL SALE TABLE"

```
select kd_op_beli_tunai as id_sold, sum(harga_satuan * jumlah) as total_sold
from t_rinci_beli_tunai
group by kd_op_beli_tunai
```

result 2

[image]

what i want is like this one

[image]

and this is what i have tried

```
 select bt.tanggal as date_sold, count(bt.kd_op_beli_tunai) as quantity_id_sold, sum(rbt.harga_satuan * rbt.jumlah) as total_sold
    from t_pembelian_tunai as bt, t_rinci_beli_tunai as rbt
    where bt.kd_op_beli_tunai = rbt.kd_op_beli_tunai
    GROUP by tanggal
    ORDER by tanggal DESC
```

the result for that is

[image]

Comment: use average instead of count. From count(bt.kd_op_beli_tunai)  ? Do avg(bt.kd_op_beli_tunai)

Comment: it's closed by 1 answers

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query.

```
SELECT  bt.tanggal as date_sold,bt.quantity_id_sold,rbt.total_sold
FROM
(
    select kd_op_beli_tunai,
           tanggal, 
           count(kd_op_beli_tunai) as quantity_id_sold
    from t_pembelian_tunai
    group by tanggal,kd_op_beli_tunai
)bt
INNER JOIN 
(
    select kd_op_beli_tunai, sum(harga_satuan * jumlah) as total_sold
    from t_rinci_beli_tunai
    group by kd_op_beli_tunai
)rbt on bt.kd_op_beli_tunai = rbt.kd_op_beli_tunai 
ORDER by bt.tanggal
```

Comment: Could your provide some sample data from `t_pembelian_tunai` and `t_rinci_beli_tunai` tables?